# Time-based conditional query

Tags: ruby, postgresql

Suppose I have the following `Server` data model:

```
Server
-> created_at Timestamp
-> last_ping Timestamp
```

A "stale" `Server` is defined as a `Server` whose `last_ping` occurred more than one hour ago (i.e., `last_ping < Time.now - 1 hour`). It should be destroyed if there exists another non-stale server that has come online (`created_at`) within one hour of the `last_ping` of the stale server.

How can I find all the `Servers` that should be destroyed? What would a query look like for this?

Comment: `Server.where(Server.arel_attribute(:last_ping).lt(1.hour.ago))` should get you all the "stale" Servers. I am a bit confused on the rest. How are the Servers related to each other in a way that we can determine if  "another non-stale server...has come online" is it just any other Server has come online?

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for your reply. Imagine that it's 12:00 right now. Stale Server A's `last_ping` occurred at 11:00. Non-stale Server B was `created_at` 11:30. In this case, Server A should be destroyed because there exists some server Server B that came online within one hour of Server A's `last_ping`.

Comment: Right so if any server has "come online" in the last hour destroy all Servers in the previous query. Correct?

Comment: That sounds about right, yes.

Comment: `Server.where(Server.arel_attribute(:last_ping).lt(1.hour.ago)).destroy_all if Server.where(Server.arel_attribute(:created_at).gteq(1.hour.ago)).exists?` should work

Comment: @engineersmnky in Rails 6.0.X+ you can use `Server.where(last_ping: ...1.hour.ago).destroy_all if Server.exists?(last_ping: 1.hour..)`. See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36696

Comment: @max that is amazing. Thank you for the heads up. A little less explicit and I can foresee confusion around equality but either way it is nice to see them working around some of the short comings of the high level DSL rails provides.

Answer (score 1):

Something like…

```rb
def clean_stale_servers
  return unless Server.exists?(last_ping: 1.hour..)

  Server.where(last_ping: ...1.hour.ago)
    .destroy_all # .delete_all is faster, use that if possible
end
```

Then you can call the `clean_stale_servers` method periodically, i.e. from a cronjob.